# isError key is false when status code returned 422 from server in react-query

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-query

React query error not throwing when status code 422 send back to client from admin. Here below is the screenshot of this issue

[image]

This is a react-query mutation object. In the error key it should show error message but it showing null.

Here below is the query

```
export const signin = (user) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/signin`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response);
      else return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => err);
};
```

Can anyone please help me about what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Remove `.catch((err) => err)`. It's doing nothing but turning your rejected promise into a resolved one

Comment: Thank you so much bro. Now it is working! Can you please upvote it so that other user can get help from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.catch((err) => err);`

is the culprit here. It takes the Error and transformed it into a resolved Promise, which is not what you want. Remove it and it should work.